# how to pass the text entered in entry box in tkinter from one function to another?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I m tying to pass the entery box text from one function to another but it gives me error that the variable itself is not defined.Here is my code.

```
from Tkinter import *
def mhello():
    mtext=ment.get()
    print mtext
def main():
    root=Tk()
    ment=StringVar()
    root.title('Test')
    mlabel=Label(root,text='Enter Text').pack()
    mentry=Entry(root,textvariable=ment).pack() 
    mbutton=Button(root,text='Click Me',command=mhello).pack()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it gives the error as:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "pygui.py", line 3, in mhello
mtext=ment.get() 
NameError: global name 'ment' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you have a variable scope issue, variables defined in functions are local to those functions so `ment` is defined in `main` but not in `mhello`. Either pass the variable in to `mhello` or make `ment` a global. So we can pass in the variable like this:

```
def mhello(var):
    mtext=var.get()
    print(mtext)
```

Then we need to call this from our button:

```
mbutton=Button(root, text='Click Me', command=lambda: mhello(ment)).pack()
```

And we need to actually call the `mainloop` for the code to run properly:

```
root.mainloop()
```

Without that no GUI will be run.

On a design level I usually create classes to store the variables that are in the same parts of the GUI to avoid needing to pass a lot of parameters around.

Comment: Tried to pass it but still the same issue

Comment: Passing the variables is a bit tricky so I edited to show how you can do that, this code is tested as working for me on python 3.5

Comment: Thanx will try and tell if the problem persist

Comment: Need one more help how to clear the text written on gui by Label command to write new like:

Comment: If you have a different question ask a new question.